# How do I code a button to start out greyed out and disabled until an imageview is populated?

Tags: java, android, button, imageview

I want to have a button greyed out until the user populates an imageview with a desired image from their phone's gallery.  How would I code this to have the button's default state to be greyed out (and disabled) but once an image is showing in the imageview, the button is enabled and no longer greyed-out to the user?

Comment: more detail please, add your code so we can see what you are doing and we can try to help.

Comment: are you at setting myButton.setEnabled(false); at the start?

Answer (score 4):

`myButton.setEnabled(false);` did u try this? this will make your botton look grayed and not listen for click events!!

call    `myButton.setEnabled(true);` if you want to listen for click events an turn your button On

you can also see this [link](http://shikii.net/blog/android-button-background-image-pressedhighlighted-and-disabled-states-without-using-multiple-images/) if you want to make a custom button